# How do I prevent displaying popup labels on the Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have several programs pinned to the taskbar in Windows 10. If a program is not running, mousing over the icon of a program will display a small popup label showing the name of the program, like this:

[image]

That label can be really annoying at times. For example, if I have a game running and it is maximized, but not in full screen mode, I will sometimes accidentally mouse over a program on the taskbar and that label can obscure part of the screen. For example, several games I play have a button or inventory bar at the bottom of the screen.

How do I disable that little popup label in Windows 10? I experimented with several taskbar settings but nothing worked.

Comment: It should not happen. A few things I can think of: Increase the tooltip timer, set taskbar to auto-hide, put game to full screen. EDIT: oh, you mention you have a game maximized, so the taskbar is still visible. Yes, then it will happen.

Comment: see this:: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-taskbar-preview-thumbnails-in-windows-10/